# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcaffe

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, caffe, ld

I installed Caffe-cpu on my Ubuntu 18.04 via the apt-get command, as it instructs on their [official website](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html):

```
sudo apt install caffe-cpu
```

But when trying to run a sample from a [git repo](https://github.com/Pratik08/Vis-DSS), it needs the header files (`caffe.hpp`). For that, I downloaded the latest Caffe Git repo and pointed to the sources. But it also complains at the make time:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcaffe
```

My understanding of similar problems is that apparently it needs to link to `caffe.so`, but I can't find it anywhere on my machine. What's the problem? How to fix it?

Comment: [How do I search for available packages from the command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/160897)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt install libcaffe-cpu-dev
```

It's widely known that to use some library on Ubuntu, we need to install `libxxx-dev` package.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: It's widely known that to use some library on Ubuntu, we need to install `libxxx-dev` package.

Comment: Yes, but we don't like code only answers here. Adding just one or two sentences that make your answer more readable would be great!

Comment: OK, Ok, ok. I just now add completely same text that already commented.

Comment: @yumetodo didn't know that before...especially that Caffe website itself didn't mention it. Does this rule apply to ALL libraries?!

Comment: Guess then I don't make the cut to be in "widely knowing" group. "Narrator: It wasn't widely known outside the cult."

Comment: AFAIK, this rule can be applied to almost all library.
If you run `apt search caffe-cpu`, you could notice `libcaffe-cpu-dev`.

Comment: @TinaJ It's applicable for the libraries you'd like to use in development since the `dev` packages includes header files that you need to compile and debug versions of the libraries etc.. To use an already release-compiled program, you won't need the `dev` packages. It's similar on many platforms.